# Maximum number of gRPC connections benchmark

Tags: grpc

I want to know how many clients can have an open connection
to an gRPC server running on an average machine.
The clients should connect to the server and open a stream.

Thus I am searching for a benchmark on how many gRPC streams
a gRPC server can handle.

Answer (score 8):

There is currently no such benchmark to my knowledge; however, I will attempt to answer what I think is your question.

In terms of the number of gRPC connections, your typical gRPC server will be bounded by the amount of memory those connections take up. Based on data we've collected in the past, a channel will take up on the order of 40 KB of memory on the server side. So taking into account the amount of memory your server has available, you can estimate the max number of gRPC connections that your server will accept.

If you want to dynamically control how much memory gets used (and, thus, how many connections get accepted), gRPC has a ResourceQuota object that you can configure [1]. If accepting a connection would put the server over the resource quota, your server will instead refuse the connection. This provides a much better alternative to OOM'ing.

[1] https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_resource_quota.html